# My SQL pivot query is returning an error though there doesnt seem to be one

Tags: php, sql, pivot

My SQL query is:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM transactions) AS T1
PIVOT(SUM(amount) FOR month IN([March], [April], [May])) AS pvt
```

My Table is as follows:

```
id  payee       amount  month    
1   Tom         90      March
3   Tom         66      April
4   Tom         89      May
10  Jasmine     125     April
11  Nancy       151     March
12  Jasmine     175     April
13  Nancy       152     April
```

My desired output is:

```
payee       March  April   May
Tom         90     66      89
Jasmine     --     300     --
Nancy       151    152     --
```

I am running this query in a phpMyAdmin for my website the Error presented is as follows:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PIVOT(SUM(amount) FOR month IN([March], [April], [May])) AS pvt

Comment: there is no `pivot` in mysql.

Comment: I don't see how `id` is computed in the desired output.

Comment: @vkp... So there is no way to do pivots in mysql? Or is there a diff keyword?

Comment: @Dario, That was a typo from copy&paste, I only need the table with the payee and the amount they paid each month. Edited the post and removed id column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `PIVOT` in MySQL, no `CROSSTAB`, no similar syntax. You have to build pivot tables by hand. A common technique is called *conditional aggregation,* and can be used this way:

```
SELECT `payee`
    , SUM(CASE WHEN `month` = 'March' THEN `amount` END) AS `March`
    , SUM(CASE WHEN `month` = 'April' THEN `amount` END) AS `April`
    , SUM(CASE WHEN `month` = 'May' THEN `amount` END) AS `May` 
  FROM `transactions`
  GROUP BY `payee`;
```

`GROUP BY` is crucial, because it restricts the scope of the aggregate function `SUM`. It is applied before calculation and it says there has to be only one output record per value of `payee`. Then I could write `SUM(amount)` to compute the sum of all amounts for that value of `payee` *(ordinary aggregation)* but I insert another condition `SUM(CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END)` and I do *conditional aggregation.*

Using `SUM` without `GROUP BY` would compute the sum across the whole table.

Comment: Sweet this does it!! Last question before marking it the answer. I've yet to grasp the use of GROUP BY, is GROUP BY applied before calculation? (As opposed to ORDER BY which is applied post result generation)

Comment: Perfect, Thanks!